# About Recursive function with Number of Islands Problem

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

## Description of Number of Islands

Given a 2d grid map of '1's (land) and '0's (water), count the number of islands. An island is surrounded by water and is formed by connecting adjacent lands horizontally or vertically. You may assume all four edges of the grid are all surrounded by water.

**Example 1:**

```py
Input: grid = [
  ["1","1","1","1","0"],
  ["1","1","0","1","0"],
  ["1","1","0","0","0"],
  ["0","0","0","0","0"]
]
Output: 1
```

**Example 2:**

```py
Input: grid = [
  ["1","1","0","0","0"],
  ["1","1","0","0","0"],
  ["0","0","1","0","0"],
  ["0","0","0","1","1"]
]
Output: 3
```

I am trying to tag each Island with '2' using recursive function:

```py
def tag_elements(grid: List[List[str]], tag, i, j):
    if grid[i-1][j] == '1':
        grid[i-1][j] = tag
        return tag_elements(grid, tag, i-1, j)
    elif grid[i+1][j] == '1':
        grid[i+1][j] = tag
        return tag_elements(grid, tag, i+1, j)
    elif grid[i][j-1] == '1':
        grid[i][j-1] = tag
        return tag_elements(grid, tag, i, j-1)
    elif grid[i][j+1] == '1':
        grid[i][j+1] = tag
        return tag_elements(grid, tag, i, j+1)
    else:
        return grid

grid[1][1] = '1'
tag_elements(grid, str(tag), 1, 1)
```

```py
The input is
grid = 
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
 ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0'], 
 ['0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0'], 
 ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]

---
What I expect to get is
grid = 
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
 ['0', '2', '2', '2', '2', '0', '0'], 
 ['0', '2', '2', '0', '2', '0', '0'], 
 ['0', '2', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]

---
But The incorrect result I have got is 
grid = 
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], 
 ['0', '2', '2', '1', '1', '0', '0'], 
 ['0', '2', '2', '0', '1', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '2', '2', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']]
```

**Now, I am so confused of recursive function and why my recursive function doesn't work. Is there anyone able to help me with that, I really appreciate it.**

Answer (score 1):

You `return` too early. A tagged element only recurse into the first land neighbour, and is not given a chance to inspect the rest.